# What is "myid" in ZingChart docs?

Tags: jquery, zingchart

I must be missing something simple, but...: In the ZingChart docs for the API methods, the functions all reference `myid`, but I can't figure out what is a ZingChart's id. For example, method [`getseriesvalues`](http://www.zingchart.com/reference/api-methods.html#zingchart__exec__api__getseriesvalues):

```
zingchart.exec('myid', 'getseriesvalues', {});
```

What does `'myid'` refer to in this example code?

Here is my simple ZingChart example code:

```
 $(function(){
    var myChart = {
        type : "line",
        title : {text: "Hello ZingChart World!"},
        series : [
            {values:[5, 10, 15, 5, 10, 5]},
            {values:[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]}
        ]
    };

    zingchart.render({
        id : "myChartDiv",
        height : 450,
        width : 600,
        data : myChart
    }); 
})
```

Now let's say I would want to invoke the `getseriesvalues` method on this chart - what would myid be? `myChart`? `myChartDiv`? Neither of them work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` property references the `<div>` element's `id` property in which the chart is injected. See the [ZingChart "Getting Started" guide](http://www.zingchart.com/reference/introduction.html).

Example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var myChart = {
                type   : "line",
                title  : {text: "Hello ZingChart World!"},
                series : [
                    {values:[5, 10, 15, 5, 10, 5]},
                    {values:[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]}
                ]
            };

            window.onload=function(){
                zingchart.render({
                    id : "myChartDiv",
                    height : 450,
                    width : 600,
                    data : myChart
                });
            };
        </script>

        <div id="myChartDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It also used for other ZingChart methods (e.g., [to subsequently bind events to your chart](http://www.zingchart.com/reference/object.html#zingchart__bind)). For example, to get the values after initiation for this chart:

```
zingchart.exec("myChartDiv", "getseriesvalues", {});
```

You can think of `id` as a global variable—always referencing the same chart by name, no matter its place in the code.

Comment: I understand that and have it working. My question is, if I would want to then invoke some method on that chart, e.g. getseriesvalues, how would I do that? What would I put as myid in `zingchart.exec('myid', 'getseriesvalues', {});`?

Comment: Sorry. `myid` in that function would be replaced with `myChartDiv`. If `myChartDiv` doesn't work, as you suggest in your question, than you have a larger issue. A link to a test page you're using, or a larger code sample would be helpful. 

I've updated my answer for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, now that I know that for certain I was able to pinpoint the real issue. It seems that the chart had not finished loading when that line of code executed (on the next line after the `zingchart.render` code)... Is there a callback I should be using?

Comment: @froadie Try the setting function handlers to the `gload` or `gcomplete` Chart events. http://www.zingchart.com/reference/api-events.html

Comment: (It would be nice if this was documented in the docs... "The ID of the chart" is kind of ambiguous, as it never specifies that the ID of the div is the ID of the chart.)

Comment: Agreed, consistency in the documentation would be helpful. Please mark this answer as accepted if it's correct for future SO visitors.